# Breakpoints can't be set on certain lines in the method. Quickwatch not working for some variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.4.2

Solution Configuration is set to Debug
Under Project Properties->Build - Optimize Code is unchecked
Advanced Build Settings -> Debugging Information is set to Full

Steps: 
 1. Clean Solution
 2. Rebuild Solution
 3. Publish appropriate projects
 4. IISReset 
 5. Attach to process (w3wp.exe)

Verified in Debug->Windows->Modules that "Symbols loaded" for dll.

**I can set breakpoints on some lines but not others.**

Getting:

> "The breakpoint failed to bind"

On the very next line of code and can set a breakpoint and it works (and breaks).

Also, when I break on the next line and try to use Quick Watch on `billingAmountsDue`, `accountNumbers` or `User` I get:

> "Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is
>   not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has
>   been optimized away."

```
    public IEnumerable<Account> GetAllAccounts()
    {
        var user = GetCurrentUser(); //Breakpoint doesn't work on these 3 lines
        var accountNumbers = GetAccountNumbersForUser(user);
        var billingAmountsDue = AsyncHelpers.RunSync(() => _billingService.GetBillingForAccounts(accountNumbers.ToArray()));

        //Breakpoint on following line works
        var accounts = user.Accounts.Join(billingAmountsDue, b => b.AccountNumber, a => a.AccountNumber, (a, b) => new Account()
```

Comment: Can you check if your are running your code in debug mode or in release mode ?

Comment: I stated in my question that "Solution Configuration is set to Debug"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Debug->Windows->Modules I noticed that Optimized was `"Yes"` for the module I was trying to Debug.

The solution is:

Right-Click on the module and choose Symbol Settings. Under General select the option for "`Suppress JIT Optimization on module load (Managed Only)`".

This option can also be found under Tools->Options->Debugging->General.