# Can a breakpoint be hit in a project that isn't the primary startup project of a multiple project solution?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols

I am working in a Solution having multiple projects. The startup project and one other project of concern is the prompt of this question.

I have no issues setting/hitting breakpoints of code within the Startup project but no breakpoints are being hit in the other. Both are web apps and when the page loads the Startup project displays the main page with a link that points to a webpage in the other Project. When I click the link in the page of the Main project, it points to a page in the other project but no breakpoints are ever being hit.

Warning message when hovering over the breakpoint states, "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

Should I not be able to hit the breakpoint of the other Project which isn't designated as Startup?

I'd also add that the webpages are configured using local IIS, not IIS Express but I wouldn't think that should make a difference.

I've gone through every possible area of configuration where I've known this type of issue to happen and despite covering all basis, this error persists. I've even gone through Tools -> Options - Debugging -> Symbols and ensured the symbol server has been specified and etc.

All configurations are set to Debug. I've deleted the obj/bin/vs directories, cleaned, rebuilt and also restarted VS without any resolve.

I would have expected this problem not to still be persistent after all these steps

Comment: I would expect both projects needing to be "running in debug mode" separately.  So if you click the debug button and it only starts up the first project, then the second is not running and not in debug mode. Now I am talking from experience on server side coding where 1) I would start the front end in debug mode, then start up the server side in debug mode. But both require starting to run on its own, separately, I hope that helps.

Comment: There are many causes for that problem. Go to Debug->Windows->Modules. Find your DLL. Make sure it's not optimized. If it says it's "Optimized" try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686725/4892466

Comment: Also, make sure, in the Modules Window, that you're running the most recent version of your DLL. It may have not deployed. If the code is newer than the DLL you can't hit breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! After having tried all recommendations it turns out that a developer had changed a specific setting the Web.config to be specific to his machine which caused all the issues with the debugging. Rather complex to explain but I've noted all of the additional recommendations for future troubleshooting steps. Probably should delete the question since it does seem rather a basic principle but I think the comments are well noted.